# Equalizer not always supported, even when api >= 9?

Tags: android, operation, equalizer, audioeffect

before enabling equalizer capabilities, I check for api level to make sure it's equal or greater than 9.
From the reports I'm getting from my users, it seems that some exceptions are thrown anyway :

the code  `eq = new Equalizer(0, mp.getAudioSessionId())` can raise :

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Effect library not loaded
at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.<init>(AudioEffect.java:355)
at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.<init>(Equalizer.java:149)
```

and the code `eq.getBandLevelRange()` can raise :

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation
at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.checkStatus(AudioEffect.java:1182)
at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.getBandLevelRange(Equalizer.java:206)
```

I don't know if there is a solution, and if not I could just catch those exceptions and disable equalizer, but I need to know what's exactly causing this, so I can inform my users without frustrating them.

thanks for any help

Comment: getting same error on api level 25, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 8):

I had this same issue, and it was caused by not calling release() on my Equalizer when I was finished with it.  Apparently, the native libraries won't allow instantiation of a new AudioEffect if there are too many already in existence.

Comment: I have added release in the same class where I am initializing my equalizer and my app is working fine on all the devices except api level 25. It's getting crashed with exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AudioEffect: invalid parameter operation
So I asked a que on below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967977/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-audioeffect-invalid-parameter-operatio/40968149?noredirect=1#comment69152090_40968149